# PHP/MYSQL: Separate DATETIME to Date only at PHP Page

Tags: php, mysql

From my question,

Below is my code

```
 echo "<td>" . $row['StartTime'] . "</td>";
```

'StartTime' is a row in a database table that displays DATETIME format. Want to ask, how to display Date only at my PHP page?

Comment: You can use date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row['StartTime']))  https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to use format function of php as shows

```
 echo "<td>" .$row['StartTime']->format('Y-m-d'). "</td>";
```

Hope it helps.

Go through the documentation also

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php.

As per the comments

```
 echo "<td>" .date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row['StartTime'])."</td>";;
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.'

Comment: @Hawau Edited.Try Now.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on string

Comment: @Hawau I think your starttime field is not datetime format.

Comment: My StartTime is absolutely in DATETIME

Comment: @Hawau Try the new added section on my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202138/discussion-between-vimal-and-hawau).